# How to specify minimum checkins using Foursquare API?

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm new to all this, but I was wanting to know how I can view popular Foursquare venues by using a longitude and latitude but also narrowing the search by specifying the exact amount of checkins at a place and also providing the radius.

I've figured out how to do some of the URL but don't know what to type exactly to specify the minimum amount of checkins.

```
"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search/?ll= 42.973423,-83.738894&radius=200"
```

That is what my URL is looking like, now I need help figuring out the last bit of information.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to define a minimum number of checkins as a search parameter for the [`/v2/venues/search` endpoint](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/search).

The response of `/v2/venues/search` request contains a `stats` field with a `checkinsCount` property. This would allow you to filter the results based on a `checkinsCount` threshold.